# Find all possible values of $\alpha$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Suppose $n ≥ 0$ is an integer and all the roots of $x^3 + αx + 4 − (2 × 2016^n) = 0$ are integers.
> Find all possible values of α.

This question is from INMO 2017. The solution goes this way . . .

Let $u, v, w$ be the roots of $x^3 + αx + 4 − (2 × 2016^n) = 0.$

Then $u + v + w = 0$ and $uvw = −4 + (2 × 2016^n).$

Therefore we obtain $uv(u + v) = 4 − (2 × 2016^n).$

Suppose $n ≥ 1.$
Then we see that $uv(u + v) \equiv 4 \mod 2016^n.$

**Therefore $uv(u + v) \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $uv(u + v) \equiv 1 \mod 9.$
This implies that $u \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and $v \equiv 2 \mod 3.$**

> Can anyone help me justify what is happening in the last step? Is it a familiar theorem from Elementary Number Theory?

Comment: There are only 81 combinations of u,v mod 9 to test, did you try exhaustive search?

Comment: I believe you mean $uv(u+v)\equiv\color{red}{4}\pmod{9}$. As for the last step, consider that none of $u$, $v$ and $u+v$ can be a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 2):

From $x\equiv y\pmod{mn}$ we can conclude $x\equiv y\pmod m$ because $x=y+kmn$ for some $k$.

If $n\ge 1$ then both $3$ and $9$ are factors of $2016^n$.

So $uv(u + v) \equiv 4 \mod 2016^n$ gives $uv(u + v) \equiv 4  \equiv 1  \mod 3\quad(**)$.

Similary $uv(u + v) \equiv 4 \mod 2016^n$ gives $uv(u + v) \equiv 4   \mod 9$, so there's a typo somewhere.

From $(**),~~$ it's clear none of $u$, $v$ or $u+v$ can be $0$ modulo $3$, which narrows it to $u\equiv v\equiv1\mod 3$ or $u\equiv v\equiv2\mod 3$, but only the latter combination works in $(**)$, and we haven't used the mod $9$ equation to get this result.